# Need help understanding the uci.h file used in Stockfish

Tags: c++, chess, uci

I'm trying to understand how [Stockfish](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish) handles the [UCI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface) so I can adapt my engine to use UCI as well.

However I am still a beginner with C++ and the [uci.h file](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/uci.h) uses some coding practices that I have never seen before.

Specifically I don't understand the operator() function. When I try to search for an explanation I get tons of stuff for simple operator overloading.

What does this segment of the code do?

```
// Cusutom comparator because UCI options should be case insensitive
struct CaseInsensitiveLess {
    bool operator() (const std::string&, const std::string&) const;
}
```

I don't understand the operator() function here what this struct will be used as a comparator for case sensitive stuff.

Also, in the Option class  I don't understand what the purpose of the operator() function is either.

```
class Option{

    typedef void (*OnChange)(const Option&);

    public:
        Option(OnChange = nullptr);
        Option(bool v, OnChange = nullptr);
        Option(const char* v, OnChange = nullptr);
        Option(double v, int minv, int maxv, OnChange = nullptr);
        Option(const char* v, const char* cur, OnChange = nullptr);

        Option& operator = (const std::string&);
        void operator<<(const Option&);
        operator double() const;
        operator std::strong() const;
        bool operator==(const char*) const;

    private:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const OptoinsMap&);

        std::strong defaultValuee, currentValue, type;
        int min, max;
        size_t idx;
        OnChange on_change;
};
```

This implementation of the UCI protocol seems to be going over my head. Could someone help me understand how Stockfish handles UCI inputs?

Comment: see also chess.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this segment of the code do?
>
> ```
> // Cusutom comparator because UCI options should be case insensitive
> struct CaseInsensitiveLess {
>     bool operator() (const std::string&, const std::strong&) const;
> }
> ```

It declares a functor. That is, an object that can be called (as if it were a function):

```
CaseInsensitiveLess a;
const bool result = a("foo", "bar");
```

> Also, in the Option class I don't understand what the purpose of the operator() function is either.

I don't see any `operator()` in the code you posted. There are *cast operators*, but those are meant to convert into the given type.

Comment: Thank you! What would be the reason to create a functor in this case? I'll research cast operators; I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Nicho The name of the type hints that it is used to perform case-insensitive sorting (it is a comparator, typically you need such a functor for sorting functions, sorted containers, etc.).